# Separate logging for task queues

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, python-rq

I'm using a task queue with python ([RQ](https://python-rq.org/)). Since workers run concurrently, without any configuration messages from all workers are mixed up.
I want to organize logging such that at any time I can get the exact full log for a given task run by a given worker. Workers run on different machines, so preferably logs would be sent over the network to some central collector, but to get started, I'd also be happy with local logging to file, as long as the messages of each task end up in a separate log file.

My question has two parts:

- how to implement this in python code. I suppose that, for the "log to file" case, I could do something like this at the beginning of each task function:

```
    logging.basicConfig(filename="some_unique_id_for_this_task_and_worker.log", level=logging.DEBUG, format="whatever")
    logging.debug("My message...")
    # etc.
```

but when it comes to logging over the network, I'm struggling to understand how the logger should be configured so that all log messages from the same task are recognizable at the collector. This is purposely vague because I haven't chosen a given technology or protocol to do this collection yet, and I'm looking for suggestions.

- Assuming that the previous requirement can be accomplished, when logging over the network, what's a centralized solution that can give me the full log for a given task? I mean really showing me the full text log, not using a search interface returning events or lines (as eg, IIRC, in splunk or elasticsearch).

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but I would think that redis has all of the distributed logging one could want. Tap into that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running multiple processes (the RQ workers) you could probably use [one of the recipes in the logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes). If you want to use a `SocketHandler` and a socket server to receive and send messages to a file, you should also look at [this recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) in the cookbook. It has a part related to [running a socket listener in production](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#running-a-logging-socket-listener-in-production).